# How to list files from the path directory with folderbrowserdialog into one column data grid in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

The coding below is the function of one of my browse button.

Can I know what should I do next to list the files in a column in datagrid?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    using (var dialog = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog())
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult result = dialog.ShowDialog();
        if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            textBox1.Text = dialog.SelectedPath;           
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably what you're looking for:

Xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <DataGrid x:Name="myGrid" Grid.Row="0" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Files" Binding="{Binding}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="SetList" Click="OnClick" />
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
    private void OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (var dialog = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog())
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult result = dialog.ShowDialog();
            if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                myGrid.ItemsSource = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(dialog.SelectedPath);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: I have tried your code, but there wrote "Directory" does not exist in the current content

Comment: @JohnDing use `System.IO.Directory` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can list the files like so:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    using (var dialog = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog())
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult result = dialog.ShowDialog();
        if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            textBox1.Text = dialog.SelectedPath;
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(dialog.SelectedPath);        
    }
}
```